# Could I check in SVN, when a specific method is changed?

Tags: svn

I found out a method which is changed some time back and I need to find out who changed that method.  Tried to check the log on the file, but last 20 revisions or so not touched this method. SVN is very slow getting revision logs and comparing them (Perforce used to be fast with these operations).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`svn blame` (also known as "annotate") will show a line-by-line breakdown of who last changed each line and at what revision. However, I don't know where that's performed - if it's slow at getting revision logs for you, `blame` may take too long. Worth a try though.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon Skeet, Annotate option worked great. 
The delay I was talking about is relative one. Perforce (P4V) is better compared to SVN when comparing two revisions or showing diff b/w two revisions.